# Static message queue

Tags: c++

I have different logical units on a microcontroller that must be able to communicate to each other. These units I will call components.

Each component has a message queue with a fixed size defined at compile time. I don't want any dynamically allocated memory.

Every component has a array of message slots. A slot can have three different states:

- Unused
- Reserved
- Processable

If component A wants to send a message to component B first it needs to reserve a message slot. It can directly write into the message data of this slot. Finally it needs to set the slot as processable. Now component B can process the data and set the slot to unused again. The order will be important but for the moment I ignore it.

```
class CommunicationManager {
public:
    CommunicationManager(ComponentManager& componentManager);
    MessageSlot * getMessageSlot(int componentId);

private:
    ComponentManager& componentManager;
};

class Component {
public:
    Component(CommunicationManager& communicationManager);
    virtual void process() = 0;
    MessageSlot * getMessageSlot();

    virtual ~Component();

protected:
    MessageQueue<5> messageQueue;
    CommunicationManager& communicationManager;
};
```

Messaging is done with these classes.

```
template <int size>
class MessageQueue {
public:
    MessageSlot* reserveMessageSlot();
    MessageSlot * getProcessableMessageSlot();
    bool processableMessageSlotAvailable();

private:
    MessageSlot messageSlots[size];
};

class MessageSlot {
public:
    void reserve();
    bool isReserved();
    bool isProcessable();
    void setProcessable();
    void reset();

    Message * getMessage();
private:
    Message message;

    bool reserved;
    bool processable;
};

class Message {
public:
    int sender;
    int receiver;

    int length;
    char data[8];
};
```

This way the communication works for now:

```
// sender part
MessageSlot * slot = communicationManger.getMessageSlot(SPI_COMPONENT_ID);
// fill message with data
slot->setProcessable();

// receiver part
MessageSlot * slot = messageQueue.getProcessableMessageSlot();
if (slot != 0) {
    // process message data
    // if processing was successful reset message slot
    slot->reset();
}
```

As you can see for now the user has to work with the slot class. Have you any ideas to hide the implementation? I don't want to copy any data.

My target would be something like this:

```
// sender
Message * msg = communicationManager.reserveMessage(SPI_COMPONENT_ID);
// fill message with data
```

How to signal that this message can be processed? I dont want the flag in the message data. I could say that data must be filled after this call because there is no real parallel processing. But I would not be happy with this way.

```
// receiver part
Message * msg = messageQueue.getProcessableMessage();
if (msg != 0) {
    // process message data
    // if processing was successful reset message slot
    messageQueue.messageProcessed();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go for [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) here. You use objects that clear the resource when it goes out of scope. As a partial example:

**To send:**

```
class Request {
  friend class CommunicationManager;
  Request(MessageSlot* slot);
  MessageSlot* slot_;

 public:
    Request(Request&&);
    ~Request();
    // Functions to add data into the message
};
Request::Request(Request&& other) : slot_(other.slot_) { other.slot_ = nullptr; }
Request::Request(MessageSlot* slot) : slot_(slot) {}
Request::~Request() {
  if (slot_)
    slot_->setProcessable();
}
```

**To receive:**

```
class Message {
  friend class MessageQueue;
  Message(MessageSlot* slot);
  MessageSlot* slot_;

 public:
    Message(Message&&);
    ~Message();
    explicit operator bool();
    // Functions to read data the message
};
Message::Message(Message&& other) : slot_(other.slot_) { other.slot_ = nullptr; }
Message::Message(MessageSlot* slot) : slot_(slot) {}
Message::~Message() {
  if (slot_)
    slot_->reset();
}
Message::operator bool() {
  return nullptr != slot_;
}
```

**Usage:**

```
{  // Any scope (function, condition, forced scope)
  Request req = communicationManager.reserveMessage(SPI_COMPONENT_ID);
  // Fill with data
}


{  // Any scope (function, condition, forced scope)
  Message msg = messageQueue.getProcessableMessage();
  if (msg) {
    // process message data
  }
}
```

Comment: If the receiver asks for a processable message the processing after can fail. In this case the message must stay in the queue. But I wil think about this approach, thanks.

Comment: Well either the `Message` can handle this on its own through its processing member functions, or you cant hide the explicit call to `reset`. You cant have it both ways.

Comment: If I use reserveMessage() to create a Request, the destructor may be called when leaving the method and the message set as processable even before data is copied, or am I wrong?

Comment: Almost. The trick here is the move constructor. When you return a `Request`object, the one you created inside `reserveMessage`will in fact be destroyed, but its member `slot_` will be null since the object has been moved into the calling code.